# java.io.FileNotFoundException on one computer but not another [long post]

Tags: java, windows, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a mod to generate random plants in Unreal World. I posted the initial version of the mod on the game's forum, and I've been told about an issue with the Windows version of the mod. The problem is specifically with the name generation; it just returns null for each name. The user who reported this problem to me posted this stacktrace (it's the same error repeated several times; no need to read them all):

[image]

This is the method where the error is occurring:

```
private static String getName(Random rn, boolean full) {
        try {
            String name;
            int prefix = rn.nextInt(179);
            int suffix = rn.nextInt(72);
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("srcwin\\Prefixes.txt"));   // error occurs on this line
            for (int i=0; i<prefix; i++) {
                sc1.nextLine();
            }
            name = sc1.next();
            if (name.contains("'")) {
                name += " ";
            }

            if (full || rn.nextInt(3) == 0) {
                if (rn.nextInt(3) == 0 && !name.contains(" ")) {
                    name += " ";
                }
                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("srcwin\\Suffixes.txt"));
                for (int i=0; i<suffix; i++) {
                    sc2.nextLine();
                }
                name += sc2.next();
            }

            return name;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UrWPlantMod.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This program is contained in a JAR containing the directories modwin, srcwin, and META-INF. The class files are contained in modwin, while the source code and txt files are contained in srcwin. The user who reported this problem is running Windows 10 Home (Version 1511, Build 10586). Another user, running Windows 8.1 (no other specifics given), can run this just fine, with no FileNotFoundExceptions or null names.

If it's relevant, I am running Ubuntu 14.04, with the only difference in this code being that the file path is `src/Prefixes.txt` instead of `srcwin\\Prefixes.txt`, and it runs just fine for me.

If you'd like to see the other lines of code mentioned in the stacktrace:

```
berries[i] = new Plant(getName(rn, false) + "berry " + getBerryName(rn), rn.nextInt(4)+1, getImg(rn, "berry"));
```

and

```
createBerries(rn); // the above line of code is in the method called here
```

Answer (score 1):

`new Scanner(new File("srcwin\\Prefixes.txt"))` will open the file `srcwin\Prefixes.txt` from the *current directory*.

Directories inside a Jar file cannot be access this way.

So, either the current directory is not what you think it is, or the files are not there (in folder `srcwin` on the file system).

To load content of a file inside your Jar (which is on the classpath, we presume), use [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

```
try (Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/srcwin/Prefixes.txt"))) {
    // code here
}
```

Note the change to the file name. It starts with `/` and uses `/`.

Also note that you should always close the `Scanner` when done with it (except when used with `System.in`), hence the try-with-resources block.

Comment: I will admit I'm not familiar with using getResourceAsStream(), but I tried your suggestion in the UNIX version so I could test it on my own computer and received a NullPointerException with the following stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/2KzT29ap     I'm also not certain this has to do with the fact that it's in a JAR file because the UNIX JAR works fine and the Windows JAR, as mentioned, works on Windows 8.1. It's just a Windows 10 user who's having trouble with it.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` will return null when the file is not on the classpath. Where is your file? For real? On the file system? In the jar? Both? Neither?

Comment: Try adding this line: `System.out.println(new File("srcwin\\Prefixes.txt").getCanonicalPath());` It will print the exact location where it looks for the file.

Comment: The file is in the jar. It works fine on Windows 8.1. The Windows 10 user who had this problem said they got it to work by extracting the .txt files from the jar and placing both the jar and the .txt files in a new folder called srcwin, so I think you are right about it looking in the wrong place. Is there a way to code this so it will be compatible with both Win8.1 and Win10?

Comment: Yes,if the file is in the jar and the jar is on the classpath, then the code in my answer will work. On any and all platforms.